# Transforming scala Flatten to use in Java in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am stuck in implementing Function1 in Java for an UDF to flatten the  `Seq[Map[String,Int]]`

```
Scala Code :  UDF1 joinMap = udf { values: Seq[Map[String,Int]] => values.flatten.toMap }
```

spark DF schema

```
root
 |-- rid: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- lid: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- mapArray: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: double
 |    |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = true)
```

How Do I implement similar UDF in Java.

Java code :

```
 UDF1 mode1 = new UDF1<WrappedArray<Map<Double, Integer>>, String>() {
  @Override
  public String call(WrappedArray<Map<Double, Integer>> maps) throws Exception {

    List<Map<Double, Integer>> lis = (List<Map<Double, Integer>>) JavaConverters.seqAsJavaListConverter(maps).asJava();

    System.out.println(lis.get(1));

    java.util.Map<Double,Integer> a= lis.stream().flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    return "";
  }


};
```

> ```
> error : Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 cannot be cast to java.util.Map
>   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:269)
> ```

Comment: Why would you want to write udf for it? you can use https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-

Comment: @koiralo I want to merge the maps into  one.

Comment: @koiralo spark function `flatten` only can be used for arrays of arrays not array of maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While converting the Seq[T] to List[T] Java converters will only convert the Seq to Java List, not the objects of the Seq to Java compatible objects. That is explicitly each object of the Converted Java List (Seq) also has to be converted to Java compatible object.

In above case scala.collection.immutable.Map to java.util.Map.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;

UDF1 mode1 = new UDF1<WrappedArray<scala.collection.immutable.Map<Double, Integer>>, Map<Double, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<Double, Integer> call(WrappedArray<scala.collection.immutable.Map<Double, Integer>> maps) throws Exception {
            List<scala.collection.immutable.Map<Double, Integer>> lis = JavaConverters.seqAsJavaListConverter(maps).asJava();
            Map<Double, Integer> flattenMap = new HashMap<>();
            lis.forEach(map -> {
                Map<Double, Integer> m = JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap((scala.collection.immutable.Map) map);
                flattenMap.putAll(m);
            });
            return flattenMap;
        }
    };
```

This code has Unchecked assignment warning which could be fixed.